# Extract Test Class attributes from Python

Tags: python, enterprise-architect

From Python via win32com I extract from my Enterprise Architect project all Test Cases linked to a Use Case with ID = element_id:

```
test_cases = EA.GetElementSet("select * from t_objecttests where t_objecttests.Object_ID = %d "%element_id, 2);
```

By looping on `test_cases`, I want to get Test Case's attributes.

I call them as specified in [Test Class](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/test.html)

No problem to get attributes: Notes, ObjectType, Status.

By calling the other attributes, e.g. AcceptanceCriteria and Class, I get an AttributeError.

How to get them?

Comment: `GetElementSet` returns a collection of `EA.Element`, not a collection of `EA.Test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the according test objects from your object like in this pseudo-code:

```
elem = repository.getElementById(<your test element id>)
test = elem.test.getAt(0)
print test.AcceptanceCriteria
```